# Dynamically Adding row with jQuery is not working with Select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my form I have an input and select fields. With the code below rows can get added dynamically on clicking Add row button. However after adding 2 select rows, the jQuery stopped working. I tried many approaches but failed to make it work. Also tried adding the dropdown list in the ViewBag property and passing it in jQuery but still no success.

Below is my code

View

```
<div style="width:700px; padding:5px; background-color:white;">
<form action="/SendDSR/AddDsr" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="UgokOCFRFUqBT7l2lHFCloLmDf6388pD7WwFMCyA2egHbAYjEVODbDx0r-jIClvtvELLq-zdTPB0C9e9ZM4wx3BrRwsqfWb2cZXZ72RHpQBqjW5-NRKRdMoND8Slii2BzEd02oITPVPCVBdBJezUTQ2" />            <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary"
                    id="addBtn" type="button">
                Add New Row
            </button>
        <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Project</th>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th class="status">Status</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
                    <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                        <td><select class="form-control proj" name="[0].ProjectsList"><option value="1">MCY</option>
<option value="2">TWM</option>
<option value="3">KHL</option>
<option value="4">PTS</option>
</select></td>
                        <td><input class="form-control task" name="[0].Task" required="required" type="text" value="" /></td>
                        <td><select class="form-control stdrod" name="[0].Status"><option selected="selected" value="Completed">Completed</option>
<option value="InProgress">InProgress</option>
<option value="ToDo">ToDo</option>
<option value="Blocker">Blocker</option>
</select></td>
                    <td><input class="id" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field UserId must be a number." data-val-required="The UserId field is required." name="[0].UserId" type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
                    <td><input class="email" name="[0].Email" type="hidden" value="riyaz_shaikh@external.mckinsey.com" /></td>
                    <td><input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." name="[0].Date" type="hidden" value="2/2/2024 12:00:00 AM" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
        </table>
```

jQuery

```
$("#addBtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
    var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
    var e = $(".email").val();
    var id = $(".id").val();
    var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

    debugger;
    var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
    $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove btn btn-warning" id="delete">Remove</a>');
    $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
        // Replaced Name
        var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
        var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
        $(this).attr('name', newN);
        //Replaced value
        var type = $(this).attr('type');
        if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
            $("#id").attr('value', id);
            $("#email").attr('value', e);
        }

        // If you have another Type then replace with default value
        $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

    });
    $trLast.after($trNew);

    // Re-assign Validation
    var form = $("form")
        .removeData("validator")
        .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
});
```

Comment: @Death-is-the-real-truth updated, please take a look

Comment: change code like this: `if (type !== undefined && type.toLowerCase() == "text") {` also Unable to see `addNew` id in your HTML it seems like `addBtn` is the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is first element is a select box so

```
var type = $(this).attr('type');
```

Is coming as `undefined` (because for select box `.prop(type)` will work)

So change your code like this and it will work for you:

```
if (type !== undefined && type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
```